# Error running Akka-Sample-Twitter-Streaming Activator Template

Tags: akka

Akka newbie. Trying to learn the latest Akka Http Streams API from this: http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/akka-sample-twitter-streaming ; I'm running into bizarre behavior with that; and posted my list of questions and what I've tried in the Disqus comments just under that Template. Hoping someone with reliable current experience with the Akka Http Streams API could please help with suggestions for where to find answers to my questions, please. THANKS!

Comment: Posted the following updates on troubleshooting build.sbt dependency errors on this Activator Template in the comment section here:  http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/akka-sample-twitter-streaming            This seems to indicate that dependency libraries need to be uploaded to the central global Maven repo to use Scala v2.12.x.    Hopefully, someone else has recently tried this Activator Template; and run into these issues and can recommend solutions!

Comment: Posted questions to GitHub repo of the original contributor for this Activator Template.  Would be thrilled if anyone else trying out this template could please comment on how they got past these (current) library compatibility issues; and/or could expand on the documentation for this template also!  It simply looks like the libraries have moved since the original template was published; and I'm sure this all was working great at some point in the past.  Thankful for the original template in any case!  GitHub repo here:  https://github.com/vrcod/akka-sample-twitter-streaming/issues